# how to make the caption on the left of the image

Tags: captions

[image][image]

This is my final image I want to make using latex
I write my paper using latex, and I meet this problem.
how to make the caption on the left of the image as above picture?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you please provide a miminal working example (MWE)? It is important to know the documentclass you're using. If you use a KOMA-script class for example there is the option `captions=centeredbeside`.

Comment: I mean to write code using latex,but I want to know how to make the total image like above image

Comment: That doesn't change that we need a MWE to see what your whole document looks like (documentclass, relevant packages, the placeholder for the image with captions).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{ *{2}{c @{\hspace{1\tabcolsep}} c @{\hspace{1\tabcolsep}} c} }
            \rotatebox{90}{\hspace{0.4cm}1-Text} & %getting the rotated text centred has do be done by hand.
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \rotatebox{90}{\hspace{0.4cm}2-Text} & 
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image} \\
             & A-Text & B-Text & & C-Text & D-Text
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{caption}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `rotating` package has the command `\rotcaption` to rotate captions. See the manual of the caption package.